# Can Android 2.3 SDK cross compile to earlier versions?

Tags: android, cross-compiling, backwards-compatibility

I have an Android app that's been on the market since v1 of the OS.  I haven't touched it since and thus forgot all that there was to forget about developing for Android.

With the new Android 2.3 SDK, can I compile my app so that users of previous OS releases can also use it (say 1.6 or 2.1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Just put [minSdkVersion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) in your Manifest.

Comment: Thanks. It's all coming back now.  One more question: how likely is my application to work right out of the box with Android 2.3?

Comment: Gotta disagree with Sheikh on this one - it's pretty likely that your app will work with very few (if any) changes, though you may need to tweak a few layouts and change a handful of manifest flags here and there - check the SDK release notes. Very few things have been deprecated or don't work anymore. A lot of new things have been added that can break *backwards* compatibility if you start using it now, locking out older versions, but remarkably few changes have broken *forwards* compatibility, and most of those have been in fairly minor.

Comment: Absolutely. Android backwards compatibility is pretty good. It is very likely that it will work out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Android has changed A LOT since the very first version.
many things have been deprecated or aren't supported anymore.
You should check what's you application is using that's not being supported now.
2.3 has got major changes in everything including the Dalvik.
The things it has stopped supporting will crash if your app uses them.
I would suggest a revamp of the APIs that your app is using.

Comment: There's a big difference between "deprecated" and "no longer works." Many things have been deprecated because they were unclear or easy to misuse, and they were replaced with better APIs. Very, very few things no longer work in newer platform versions and those decisions were not made lightly. Service#setForeground and ActivityManager#restartPackage are good examples. Using either one will not prevent an older app from functioning (the app will not crash) but they will not have the originally expected result.

Comment: OKay perhaps my words have been sarcastic, but I did mean almost the same thing :-) I edited my words too!