# How can I modify my existing app to support an earlier version of the Android OS?

Tags: android

I upgraded my app from [Android 2.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Eclair) (Eclair) to [Android 2.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Froyo) (Froyo), but I didn't realize that most of my users are still running Android 2.1. Now they can't get the update anymore. Can I downgrade my app to Android 2.1?

Comment: Close voters: This isn't a superuser-applicable question.

Comment: see this question: [Can Android 2.3 SDK cross compile to earlier versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373489/can-android-2-3-sdk-cross-compile-to-earlier-versions)

Comment: See also: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FhsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the minSDKVersion (API 7 is is 2.1 compatible, I believe) to the appropriate API in the manifest and make sure all your code is compliant. You can find information about this in the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)